# Salesforce DB connect with SQL Management Studio

Tags: soql, force.com, database, sqlserver

I'm trying to connect SQL Server Management Studio to Salesforce so I can see tables and columns but unable to connect. Do I need any ADO.net connector or Salesforce plugin for this to work? Do I need to change port number or any other setting? I'm using password+token in the password field. I know Real Force is a recommended way to connect and I'm able to do so but would like to connect it with SQL management studio as well if possible.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Salesforce DB is not as MS SQL Database, so I believe you can not achieve that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Salesforce does not use SQL Server, so you can't just connect from SQL Server Management Studio. A quick Google search found at least one product that claims to allow you to connect from Management Studio: https://www.devart.com/news/2015/odbc-salesforce.html.

I've also used a product called [DBAmp](https://forceamp.com/) to connect to Salesforce from SQL Server, but I don't think it gives you features like viewing table structure.

To view tables and fields, I'd recommend looking at [Schema Builder](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/data_modeling/units/schema_builder), part of Salesforce's Setup.

Comment: Would also recomend using [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/metadataDescribeAndList.php), you can get pretty much every metadata and schema detail of your org very easily.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to connect with Salesforce directly. If you are trying to import or export data on hourly or daily basis, you can use ETL tools. If your data set is small, you can use Data Loader from command line.